# How can I connect Azure Devops Testplans to Testim.io

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, testcase

I want to be able to run my automated tests in Testim.io and have them connected to test-cases in Azure Devops Testplans.

I want a record saved of each automated test run with pass/fail metrics.

Each failed test-case should open a bug in Azure Devops

Answer (score 0):

I think that is impossible for azure devops test plan. So far, there is no way to connect test plan from azure devops to Testim.

**As a suggest**, you could [suggest a feature to the Team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to report this problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering, after some research Testim allows custom API actions so I could add to the end of each test in Testim an Azure Devops API call to the testcase to update it at least as run